# small emebedded database for spring data

Tags: spring, jpa

I try to write a small web application with a restfull frontend to manage a little amount of data (round about 30 datasets). I want to create a PDF file from the datasets (using iText, but this is not the Problem). I search now a small database, which I can embed in my application an which persists the data somewhere on my Harddisc (if possible no Client / Server database), but I find no example / tutorial for this. All tutorial I found using a database in in-Memory mode, which is not what I need. Is there somewhere a nice tutorial helping me? Which database would you sugest to use in my Situation?

Thanks for your help and
Kind regards,
Andreas Grund

Comment: You cant find an example of an embedded database? internet search reveals many. H2 is one example

Answer (score 0):

You can use H2, HSQL and Derby databases for embedded  database. For example h2 database datasource-url like below :

```
jdbc:h2:~/Desktop/Database/test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;
```

And in spring boot you can easily do it ,if you read this document [Spring Boot-Embedded Databases](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-embedded-database-support)